# Sparx Enterprise Architect Version 10 - Create Class Diagram from Source

Tags: c#, uml, enterprise-architect

I want to reverse engineer a current c# Project at work. I was told to use enterprise architect. But where can I select to import the source code? I am using Version 10 Corporate Edition and it seems to me there are big differences to earlier Versions. When I select a Project there are no Options like "Code Engineering" as I have seen in many youtube videos or text tutorials.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Somehow some options were hidden in the default profile .... great. Reconfigured the profile and now it works.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

The top-most level in the model tree consists of one or more "root nodes", sometimes referred to as "models" in the help file. One of these is created when the project is created, by default it is called "Model".

This level is only for organizing model packages and is very restricted in what you can do with it. You cannot place diagrams or classes directly under a root node, and you cannot reverse-engineer code to a root node. Root nodes are not, strictly speaking, UML packages.

Instead, you must create a package in the root node. The first level below the root is called "view", but view packages are regular UML packages and you can do anything with them, including show them in diagrams, draw connectors to them and import code into them.

When you create a view, EA asks you what icon to display. This is GUI sugar only, and has no effect on what you can place inside the package.

The thing to keep in mind is that while you can move regular packages freely around the tree if you want, you cannot move root nodes or view packages to other levels. In other words, you cannot turn a view into a root node and you cannot place a view inside another view. For this reason, it might be a good idea to create a regular package inside your view before you import your code.

So: create a view inside the "Model" root node, and preferably another package in the view. You will be able to import code into either.

Addendum after the screenshot was added:

You need at least the [Professional license](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html#editions) to do code engineering at all. If you've got that, you're either working in a project where you don't have the necessary privileges to do reverse engineering (and need to contact the project administrator to get it), or you've selected a command set that doesn't include it.

EA 10, on first start after installation, asks if you wish to customize the GUI. This actually means that a number of menu items are removed. If you can't find a menu item, go to View -- Workspaces and Commands -- Commands, and select Complete.

Comment: The big quest is. HOW to import the code? See my screenshot. It seems there is no option for this.